# What triggers Expired Password Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, change-password

I want to write up a custom page for the expired password page. I am unable to find the page that is related to the expired password page, my assumption is that it is the same VFP as the `changePassword.vfp` but I hate to assume.

Can anyone confirm that this is the page? If not, can anyone point me in the direction of the correct page and how the expired password page is triggered and sent out?

I usually would trigger the expired password page and be able to trace it back to the VFP but because I can't set the expiration date manually or programmatically I am unable to force test and am blindly poking around.

Thank you!

Comment: Is that "Password expired" visualforce page for community?

Comment: yes it is for community

Comment: There is one trick you can try -- in case if you call in apex ```System.setPassword('userid','simple');``` with simple password, on the very first login of the user with simple password it might(!) ask you to update your password, so it should be expired password page

Comment: is this the expired page or just a reset page? I am curious what triggers the expired page flow.

Comment: @kurunve also, I attempted this hack you provided and I did not receive any emails about expired an password